# ReactJs: Get data from parent URL and pass it to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post

I am sending a form data from a form in reactjs. Some pre inputs from the user have to be sent altogether with the form. I get that data from the URL of the parent file and the form is in the child component.

Parent url:
http://localhost:3000/uploadlist?phmcy=2

I have to get the phmcy value from the URL. (Here the data have to be passed is '2').

parent component:

```
import Upload froimportm './Upload'
import axios from "axios";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { useLocation } from 'react-router';

export default function Uploadlist() {
    let phmcy = (new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)).get("phmcy")

    var myphmcy = JSON.stringify(phmcy);
    //const phmcyvalue = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
    //const phmcy = phmcyvalue.get('phmcy')
    console.log(myphmcy);


    const ordersAPI= (url='https://localhost:44357/api/Orders') => {
        return {
            fetchAll: () => axios.get(url),
            create: newRecord => axios.post(url, newRecord),
            update: (id, updateRecord) => axios.put(url + id, updateRecord),
            delete: id => axios.delete(url+id)
        }
    }
 
    const addOrEdit = (formData, onSuccess) => {

        ordersAPI().create(formData)
        .then(res => {
            onSuccess();
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data))
    }

    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid py-4 "></div>
            <div className="container text">
                <h1 className="display-4"> Order Register</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4 offset-3">
                <Upload
                    addOrEdit = {addOrEdit}
                    myphmcy = {myphmcy}
                />
                </div> 
                <div className="col-md-1">
                    <div> </div>
                </div>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Child component: (This is where the form is. I have only included a part)

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


import  myphmcy from './Uploadlist';

//const myphmcy = JSON.stringify(phmcy);
console.log(myphmcy);
const defaultImageSrc = '/images/7.jpg';


const initialFieldValues ={
    orderId:0, 
    dateTime:'',
    status:'',
    status2:'',
    pharmacyName:'',
    customerName:'',
    patientName:'',
    patientAge:'',
    address:'',
    email:'',
    teleNo:'',
    customerId:1,
    pharmacyId:myphmcy,//data obtaind from the URL have to posted as the pharmacyID when posting. 
    imageName:'',
    imageSrc:'',
    imageFile: null
    
}


export default function Upload(props) {

    const {addOrEdit} = props

    const {myphmcy} = props

    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialFieldValues)
    const[errors, setErrors] = useState({})

    const handleInputChange= e => {
        const {name, value} = e.target;
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [name]:value
        })
        
    }

    const showPreview = e => {
        if(e.target.files && e.target.files[0]){
            let imageFile = e.target.files[0];
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = x => {
                setValues({
                    ...values,
                    imageFile,
                    imageSrc : x.target.result
                    
                })
                
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(imageFile)
        }

        else{
            setValues({
                ...values,
                imageFile:null,
                imageSrc:''
            })
        }

    }

    const validate = () => {
        let temp = {}
        temp.customerName = values.customerName == "" ? false : true;
        setErrors(temp)
        return Object.values(temp).every(x => x == true)
    }

    const resetForm = () => {
        setValues(initialFieldValues)
        document.getElementById('image-uploader').value = null;
    }

    const handleFormSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (validate()){
        
        const formData = new FormData()
        
        formData.append('orderId',values.orderId)
        formData.append('dateTime',values.dateTime)
        formData.append('status',values.status)
        formData.append('status2',values.status2)
        formData.append('pharmacyName',values.pharmacyName)
        formData.append('customerName',values.customerName)
        formData.append('patientName',values.patientName)
        formData.append('patientAge',values.patientAge)
        formData.append('address',values.address)
        formData.append('email',values.email)
        formData.append('teleNo',values.teleNo)
        formData.append('customerId',values.customerId)
        formData.append('pharmacyId',values.pharmacyId)
        formData.append('imageName',values.imageName)
        formData.append('imageFile',values.imageFile)
        addOrEdit(formData, resetForm) 

        alert("Your file is being uploaded!")
    }
}

const applyErrorClass = field => ((field in errors && errors[field] == false) ? ' invalid-field' : '')


    

    return (
        <>
        <div className="container text-center ">
            <p className="lead"></p>
        </div>
        <form autoComplete="off" noValidate onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
            <div className="card">
                <div className="card-header text-center">Place Your Order Here</div>
            
            <img src={values.imageSrc} className="card-img-top"/>

                <div className="card-body">

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="file" accept="image/*" className="form-control-file" onChange={showPreview} id="image-uploader"/> 
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="datetime-local" className="form-control" placeholder="Date Time" name="dateTime" value={values.dateTime}
                       onChange={ handleInputChange}/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input className="form-control" placeholder="Enter the prescription items and qty" name="status" value={values.status} onChange={ handleInputChange}/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input className="form-control" placeholder="What are the symptoms?" name="status2" value={values.status2} onChange={ handleInputChange}/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input className="form-control" placeholder="Pharmacy Name" name="pharmacyName" value={values.pharmacyName} onChange={ handleInputChange}/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input className={"form-control" + applyErrorClass('customerName')}  placeholder="Your Name" name="customerName" value={values.customerName} onChange={ handleInputChange}/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input className="form-control" placeholder="Patient Name" name="patientName" value={values.patientName} onChange={ handleInputChange}/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input className="form-control" placeholder="Patient Age" name="patientAge" value={values.patientAge} onChange={ handleInputChange}/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input className="form-control" placeholder="Delivery address" name="address" value={values.address} onChange={ handleInputChange}/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input className="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" name="email" value={values.email} onChange={ handleInputChange}/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input className="form-control" placeholder="Contact Number" name="teleNo" value={values.teleNo} onChange={ handleInputChange}/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group text-center">
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-light">submit</button>
                        
                    </div>
                    

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </>
    )
}
```

This doesn't work well and I can't post the data. Can some genius help me with this?

Comment: You should use `URL.createObjectURL(file)` to preview files not dataURLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

For some reason you import the `Uploadlist` (the default export/import) and name it `myphmcy`, save this in the initial state, and then never consume the passed `myphmcy` prop. This pattern tends to lead to stale state as you need to also handle when the prop values update so you can synchronize the state value.

## Solution

Storing passed props is anti-pattern in React, just consume the `myphmcy` prop directly in the `handleFormSubmit` submit handler. This ensure you are *always* using the latest `myphmcy` props value when submitting the form data.

```
const handleFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (validate()) {
    
    const formData = new FormData();
    
    formData.append('orderId', values.orderId);
    formData.append('dateTime', values.dateTime);
    formData.append('status', values.status);
    formData.append('status2', values.status2);
    formData.append('pharmacyName', values.pharmacyName);
    formData.append('customerName', values.customerName);
    formData.append('patientName', values.patientName);
    formData.append('patientAge', values.patientAge);
    formData.append('address', values.address);
    formData.append('email', values.email);
    formData.append('teleNo', values.teleNo);
    formData.append('customerId', values.customerId);
    formData.append('pharmacyId', myphmcy) // <-- use the prop directly
    formData.append('imageName', values.imageName);
    formData.append('imageFile', values.imageFile);
    addOrEdit(formData, resetForm) ;

    alert("Your file is being uploaded!");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the myphmcy value from props but setting it outside of the function. So it will set only undefined to the pharmacyId. You need to assign the myphmcy value inside the fnuction.